# Javascript random that saves where the random has linked to already

Tags: javascript, html, function

So I tried writing this question before and it was closed.  While I was still able to get comments, I am just assuming that I used up the amount of comments or something.  Please, I just need to know how to call the javascript function in a link so that it works.  Thank you to the person who provided the code for the function I just need to know how to call to it in a link.  Nothing I have tried works.  I have tried other javascript function searches and none of that works.

So I wrote a code for my job that is basically a quiz. It's HTML code. I wrote it so that it would be a set order for each question. Then I realized it'd be easy to memorize answers. I found a randomizer for links, but I need to know how to get it to remember which questions it's been to do they don't show up in the quiz again. Is this possible?

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Easy Mode
        </title>
     <script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body align="center">
        Welcome to Easy Mode<br>
        In this mode, menu descriptions will be given <br>
        after each image to make it easier to identify<br>
        When you are ready, click the next button below <br>
        <a href="getNextQuestion()">Next</a>


       <script> 
 var allQuestions = ["question 1.html", "question 2.html", "question 
3.html", "question 4.html"];


function getNextQuestion() {
     var questions = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("questions"));
  if (questions === null) questions = randoSequence(allQuestions);
  if (questions.length == 0) return "VICTORY.html";
  var question = questions.pop().value;
  localStorage.setItem("questions", JSON.stringify(questions));
  return question;
}


    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for all your help already given and any that will be given in the future

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "how to call the javascript function in a link" or "remember which questions it's been to"?  Take a step back from what you think the solution might be and describe the functionality you're attempting to achieve.  Are you looking to store information somewhere?  Where do you want to store it?  In some server-side database?  In the user's browser?  Somewhere else?  You're already using `localStorage`, is that what you intend to use?  If so, what are you trying to store there and how is it not working?

Comment: Also do NOT have spaces in URLs - dash or underscore (_)

Comment: I posted this question before but because it was on mobile it wouldn't let me put the spaces in for code formatting the website likes.  So the question was closed.  The function itself was given to me by a user here to save links the function went to in local storage so that it wouldn't go there again.  When it gets to the end of the possible links it's supposed to go to a final page saying you finished.

Comment: What I need to know is how do I call to the function in a link tag and have it put out the next question in the quiz because everything I've tried it just displays a page not found

Comment: And I just had a thought, does this even need a link to work properly?

Comment: As for the spaces I'm working on local for the links.  Each page is titled question then number.html

Comment: So, i just tried something different, I tried a button input instead of a link.      <input type="button" value="Next" onClick="getNextQuestion()">

This does nothing.  I think it's in the randomizer code, but I don't know how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.

Uncomment the lines with localStorage when using (SO does not allow localStorage in snippets)

the script needs to be in each page

I suggest you ajax the question in, instead.

Anyway: [working example](http://plungjan.name/ee/quiz/start.html)

```js
const allQuestions = ["question_1.html", "question_2.html", "question_3.html", "question_4.html"];
let storedQuestions;
// storedQuestions = localStorage.getItem("questions");
let questions = storedQuestions ? JSON.parse(storedQuestions) :  allQuestions;

function getNextQuestion() {
  let href = questions.length === 0 ? "VICTORY.html" : questions.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*questions.length),1);
  // localStorage.setItem("questions", JSON.stringify(questions));
  alert(href+"\n"+questions); // remove when happy
  return href;
}
```

```html
Welcome to Easy Mode<br> In this mode, menu descriptions will be given <br> after each image to make it easier to identify<br> When you are ready, click the next button below <br>
<a href="#" onclick="this.href = getNextQuestion()">Next</a>
```

**NOTE** You need to get rid of the localStorage item to be able to run the quiz again. In my victory.html I have a ***button*** with

```
<button type="button" onclick="localStorage.removeItem('questions'); location.replace('start.html')">reset</button>
```

To reset in the start page have this ONLY in the top of the script on the start page:

```
localStorage.removeItem('questions')
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208880/discussion-on-answer-by-mplungjan-javascript-random-that-saves-where-the-random).